# 3D Contour Plot - parts with gradients less and more than zero

Tags: boolean-computation, regions, plotting

I'm trying to plot sections of the 3D Contours, with gradient less than zero, and more than zero and equal to zero.

It manages to solve for the derivative, but when I apply the conditions `deriv2 < 0` or `deriv2 > 0` it gives the error:

> deriv2 < 0 must be a boolean condition

```
C1 = 10^(-1);
C2 = 0.1*C1;
R = 50;
Tb = 0.1;
Geb = 5.;
Z0 = 50;
L[Te_] := 1. + 1.*(Te - 0.1);
Zlcr[Te_, w_] := (1/R + 1/(I*L[Te]*w) + I*C1*w)^-1;
Zload[Te_, w_] := -I*w*C2 + Zlcr[Te, w];
Γ[Te_, w_] := (Zload[Te, w] - Z0)/(Zload[Te, w] + Z0);
y[Te_, w_] := (Abs[Γ[Te, w]])^2;
DeltaPlocal = 10.^-5;
eq2 = (1 -   y[Te, w]) Pprobe  ==  (Te - Tb) Geb
ContourPlot3D[ 
 Evaluate[eq2], {w, 2.5, 2.8}, {Te, 0, 0.5}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}    ]

deriv2 = Derivative[1, 0][Te][w, Pprobe] /. 
   First[  Solve[    D[eq2 /. Te ->   Te[w, Pprobe], w],  
     Derivative[1, 0][Te][w, Pprobe]  ]  ]  /. Te[w, Pprobe] ->  Te

Positive2 = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[eq2], {w, 2.5, 2.8}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 0.5}, 
  RegionFunction ->  Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2 > 0], Mesh -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> Blue, MaxRecursion -> 5]

Negative2 = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[eq2], {w, 2.5, 2.8}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 0.5}, 
  RegionFunction ->  Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2 < 0], Mesh -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> 5]

zero2 = ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[eq2], {w, 2.5, 2.8}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 0.5}, 
  RegionFunction ->  Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2 = 0], Mesh -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> Green, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

Comment: Adopted from: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56289/3d-contour-plot-parts-of-sphere-with-gradient-less-than-0-equal-to-0-and-more-t

Comment: AFAIS `deriv2` is `Complex` ...

Comment: I don't think so, as all terms in eq2 are real. y[Te,w] is the absolute value of a funtion

Comment: If you say so ..

Comment: ok if deriv2 is complex, then how do I plot it?

Answer (score 3):

Rationalize all of the definitions and equations so that there are no numerical artifacts resulting from the initial presence of the imaginary factors.

```
C1 = 1/10;
C2 = C1/10;
R = 50;
Tb = 1/10;
Geb = 5;
Z0 = 50;
L[Te_] = Te + 9/10;
Zlcr[Te_, w_] = (1/R + 1/(I*L[Te]*w) + I*C1*w)^-1;
Zload[Te_, w_] = -I*w*C2 + Zlcr[Te, w];
Γ[Te_, w_] = (Zload[Te, w] - Z0)/(Zload[Te, w] + Z0);
y[Te_, w_] = (Abs[Γ[Te, w]])^2;
DeltaPlocal = 10^-5;
```

Since you are interested in real values of {w, Te, Pprobe} use `ComplexExpand` to get rid of `Abs` in eq2.  `Abs` causes problems with derivatives. For example,

```
D[Abs[x], x]
```

> Derivative[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wQ3T.jpg)[Abs][x]

```
eq2 = (1 - y[Te, w]) Pprobe == (Te - Tb) Geb //
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  Simplify
```

> 1/2 + (100000000 Pprobe (9 + 10 Te)^2 w^2)/(6250000000000 + 
>        250000 (-4467779 - 4928200 Te + 40000 Te^2) w^2 + (50629005081 + 
>           112508950180 Te + 62505000100 Te^2) w^4 + 25 (9 + 10 Te)^2 w^6) ==   5 Te

```
cp3D = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eq2],
   {w, 25/10, 28/10}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 1/2},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {w, Pprobe, Te})];

deriv2 = Derivative[1, 0][Te][w, Pprobe] /.
      First[Solve[D[eq2 /. Te -> Te[w, Pprobe], w],
        Derivative[1, 0][Te][w, Pprobe]]] /.
     Te[w, Pprobe] -> Te // 
    N[#, 30] & // Simplify;

Positive2 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eq2],
   {w, 25/10, 28/10}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 1/2},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2 > 0],
   WorkingPrecision -> 20,
   Mesh -> False,
   ContourStyle -> Blue,
   AxesLabel ->
    (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {w, Pprobe, Te})];

Negative2 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eq2],
   {w, 25/10, 28/10}, {Pprobe, 0, 5}, {Te, 0, 1/2},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2 < 0],
   WorkingPrecision -> 20,
   Mesh -> False,
   ContourStyle -> Red,
   AxesLabel ->
    (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {w, Pprobe, Te})];
```

`zero2` appears to be an arbitrarily small region so I have skipped over it.

```
GraphicsRow[{cp3D, Show[Positive2, Negative2,
   AxesLabel ->
    (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {w, Pprobe, Te})]},
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Running your code still gives me the error "deriv2 > 0 must be a boolean function"

Comment: Works fine with v10 on my Mac. Try starting with a fresh kernel or change definition and use of deriv2 to make variable dependency explicit, i.e., deriv2[w_, Pprobe_, Te_] = ... and RegionFunction -> Function[{w, Pprobe, Te}, deriv2[w, Pprobe, Te] < 0].

Comment: I restarted mathematica, and it still doesn't work..I'm on MMA 9

Comment: In v9 the `ComplexExpand` in eq2's definition doesn't get rid of the `Abs`. Use `TargetFunctions` option in `ComplexExpand`. Change the definition of eq2 to `eq2 = (1 - y[Te, w]) Pprobe == (Te - Tb) Geb // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify`

Comment: I incorporated the changed definition of eq2 above to make the solution more robust.

Comment: Thanks alot Bob, that worked out great for positive2 and negative2, but for zero2 it still gives the entire contour. I suspect this gives the boundary between positive and negative gradient, which is simply a line. How do I show this line in the plot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16864/discussion-between-bob-hanlon-and-user44840).